# MYSQL SELECT ... FOR UPDATE Not working?

Tags: java, sql, mysql, select, jdbc

I am having issues with MySQL's SELECT .. FOR UPDATE, here is the query I am trying to run:

```
SQL = "SELECT * " +
      "FROM " + TableName + " " + 
      "WHERE out_status IN ("+outSStatus+") AND queued <= NOW() " +
      "ORDER BY out_status, id_queue ASC "+ limitSql+
      "FOR UPDATE";
```

After this, the thread will do an UPDATE and change the out_status to 99, which is then it should unlock the row.

I am running a multi-threaded java application, so 3 threads are running this SQL statement, but when thread 1 runs this, it doesn't lock (hide) its results from thread 2 & 3. Therefore threads 2 & 3 are getting the same results.

Also each thread is on its own mysql connection.

Can anybody please help me with this? OR perhaps have a better solution?

Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. Both answers, from @Vikash and @Adeel Ansari, are valid suggestions. However, I solved the issue by using `InnoDB` engine instead of `MyISAM`. `MyISAM` only allows locking on table level, not on row level. You still need transactions, when using `InnoDB`.

Comment: Excuse me, What do you mean by that? Could you please put some light on how can this be changed in a live environment. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might be working, and you are unable to notice. Say thread 1 executed the statement, and committed the transaction automatically, because `auto-commit` was on. Then of course thread 2 would be able to run that too.

Try setting `auto-commit` off, using [this method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#setAutoCommit%28boolean%29) of `Connection` class and then see the result.

Comment: I set auto-commit = off ... And with the above, I still need to use transactions for it to work? eg: BEGIN and COMMIT

Comment: @James: Okay, but at least it started working. You can accept Vikash's answer then, I suggest.